# How to echo array elements that contain a variable —PHP

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have a script that looks through a file and returns every newline as an array element.

```
$file = fopen("dict.txt", "r");
$entries = array();
while (!feof($file)) { $entries[] = fgets($file); }
fclose($file);
```

I also have a script which does some utilities with a `$_GET` variable.

```
$word = htmlspecialchars($_GET["user"]);
$letters = $word[0] . $word[1] . $word[2];
```

What I would like to do now is to `echo` all elements in the `$entries` array beginning with `$letters`.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 foreach($entries as $entry) {
     if (strpos($entry, $letters) === 0) {
         echo $entry;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It ends up echoing `$letters` and the rest of the entire list of words. :) I would like the script to echo only the array elements that begin with `$letters`.

Comment: "to echo all elements in the $entries" that is what you want??

Comment: Sort of… but "beginning with `$letters.`"

Comment: Ok, you want the letters on each element?

Comment: I want to echo only the elements whose first three letters are `$letters`.

Comment: The rest of the script looks at `$_GET['user']` and if `dict.txt` doesn't have it, it gives a filtered levenshtein suggestion. If the levenshtein fails, it resorts to echoing every element whose first three letters are `$letters`.